# デバッグ実行でのビルドに失敗します

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

お世話になっております。

Intellijを使っております。

最近行なっている開発で、GitSubモジュールを使ったGradleマルチプロジェクトがあるのですが、

SPF-----jpf-core (GitSubmodule)

---jpf-symbc

CLIでのビルドや実行は問題なくできます。

また、プロジェクトルート(SPF)を開いて、jpf-core/jpf-symbcをビルドは成功しますが、

jpf-core内にあるmainを持つモジュールのデバッグ実行をすると、失敗します。

CLIでのデバッグは非効率で、Intellijでデバッグ実行して効率を高めたいのですが、原因と対策がわかる方、いらっしゃいませんでしょうか。

可能性だけでもいいので、ご教示いただけますと幸いでございます。

Intellijバージョン　2023.1.2/2023.2.1
JDK:11(amazon corretto)
Gradle:8.2.1

実行モジュール：jpf-core:RunJPF.main()'

CP:-cp SPF.jpf-core.main

エラー：Cannot locate tasks that match ':jpf-core:RunJPF.main()' as project 'jpf-core' not found in root project 'jpf-core'.

作業ディレクトリ：~/SPF/jpf-sumbc

Comment: 再現しないのでもう少し詳しい状況の説明が必要かなと思います。

Comment: ご確認いただき誠にありがとうございます。
こちらに詳しい情報がございます。

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-326903

何卒よろしくお願い申し上げます。